# creating a graph with more than one column from a pandas dataframe using ggplot2 library

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I have been able to create a graph with the data points from a single column shown the Y axis and Dates shown along the X axis.

Is it possible using GGplot to show for example multiple columns of data from a pandas dataframe along the Y axis?

```
ggplot_obj = ggplot(df.reset_index(), aes('date','close')) + geom_line() + ggtitle(graph_title)
```

For example since I am graphing stock data I would love to be able to show High and Low and Open against the Dates. Could I maybe do something like:

```
ggplot_obj = ggplot(df.reset_index(), aes('date',['close','High','Low'])) + geom_line() + ggtitle(graph_title)
```

At the moment I am creating these graphs by looping over a list of stock_codes filtering a dataframe and sending that dataframe to ggplot to create a plot.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have all values you are mapping to `y` in one column. You could do this using `tidyr`:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyr")

mtcars$low <- mtcars$disp * 0.75
mtcars$high <- mtcars$disp * 1.25

mtcars_tidy <- gather(data = mtcars, key = "cat", value = "value", disp, low, high)

ggplot(mtcars_tidy, aes(x = mpg, y = value, color = cat)) +
  geom_line()
```